# Is "gomitar" a real word?

Tags: verbos, ortografía, palabras-raras, dialectos, deletreo

One sometimes hears children say *gomitar* in place of *vomitar*. Is this a valid word in any dialect of Spanish, or is it just a mistake that children make?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Gomitar* (as well as its derivations *gomitador, gomitadura, gómito* etc) was historically considered standard Spanish, and is recorded in dictionaries from 1495 to 1869 (beyond 1721 with the note that its use was *"antiquado"* <sup>1</sup>).

Nowadays it is not used in any prestige dialect, however, it does still survive in some rural dialects of American Spanish<sup>2 3</sup>. Specifically:

> #### [**gomitar.**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=gomitar)
>
> **I.   1.**    *CR, Pe, Bo,* rur; vulg; *Mx, PR,* vulg; pop; *ES, Co,* rur; *Ch,* pop. Vomitar.

It also exists as:

- a loan word in some American languages<sup>2</sup>
- the standard word in Ladino<sup>5 6</sup> (which split off from Old Spanish when the word still had currency in the 15-16th century)

Interestingly, though it hasn't survived in Peninsular Spanish it *is* found in some dialects of neighbouring Catalan<sup>4</sup> and Portuguese<sup>5 6</sup>.

---

**Sources:**

<sup>1. [*Nuevo Tesoro Lexicográfico de la Lengua Española*](http://buscon.rae.es/ntlle/SrvltGUILoginNtlle)</sup>
<sup>2. [*A Grammar of Huallaga (Huánuco) Quechua*](https://books.google.es/books?id=fq5js5brciAC&pg=PA476&dq=gomitar), David Weber (p.476, n.43)</sup>
<sup>3. [Diccionario de americanismos: *gomitar*](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=gomitar)</sup>
<sup>4. [Diccionari català-valencià-balear: *gomitar*](http://dcvb.iecat.net/results.asp?Word=gomitar&Id=77573&search=gomitar)</sup>
<sup>5. [*Vocabulario portuguez & latino*](http://www.cervantesvirtual.com/obra/vocabulario-portuguez-latino/), Bluteau (1721)</sup>
<sup>6. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gomitar</sup>

Answer (score 2):

There's a nice recent [article](https://verne.elpais.com/verne/2018/12/20/articulo/1545309938_546118.html) (in Spanish) on this topic in El País:

> *Agüelo, nochegüena* o *güelta* son formas comunes en la lengua poca elaborada para referirse a abuelo, nochebuena o vuelta; los ejemplos se dan muy comúnmente cuando sigue el diptongo ue pero también en otros casos como *golver, **gomitar*** o *gofetá* para volver, vomitar o bofetada.
>
> - [**La Nochebuena también es 'Nochegüena'** ¿Desde cuándo esta 'g' está mal vista?](https://verne.elpais.com/verne/2018/12/20/articulo/1545309938_546118.html)